# Python PIL/Image generate grid of images of different width/height

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I came across the following example:

```
from PIL import Image

def image_grid(imgs, rows, cols):
    assert len(imgs) == rows*cols

    w, h = imgs[0].size
    grid = Image.new('RGB', size=(cols*w, rows*h))
    grid_w, grid_h = grid.size
    
    for i, img in enumerate(imgs):
        grid.paste(img, box=(i%cols*w, i//cols*h))
    return grid

grid = image_grid(imgs, rows=3, cols=3)
```

Works great, but what I need is a way to generate a grid of images of different width/height. I haven't been able to find any such example while searching.

What I've been able to do is to iterate all images, get the max image dimensions encountered and change:

```
grid.paste(img, box=(i%cols*w, i//cols*h))
```

to:

```
grid.paste(img, box=(i%cols*maxWidth, i//cols*maxHeight))
```

But that ends up wasting a lot of space.

Perhaps to avoid this the max width/height of each column/row would have to be calculated instead, but all the ways I've tried so far don't get the job done.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: So by grid are you talking about perfectly spaced of equidistant intersecting lines thus forming perfect boxes to insert the images into, or do you just want to fit the images as tightly compact into a new image?

Comment: Fitting the images as tightly compact next to each other into a new image would be ideal. To simplify the process though, we could stick to columns and rows and just somehow check what the max should be based on current column/row.

Comment: For clarification, I am envisioning something like this https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSG27KKIsIMp_1S7kKySp4PZ2bcGkRrBPN1sg&usqp=CAU is what you are trying to achieve, just not including the overlaps.

Comment: What you've sent is more complex than what I have in mind. What I have in mind is something like what you get when you make the change that I made but that wastes space because it assigns each image the space of the biggest image in the set. We could check each column/row instead for what to assign. That way each image won't get assigned extra space than what its column/row requires.

Comment: Please try and improve your question. It is very vague and not very *"answerable"*. You seem to want a grid of images that doesn't waste space but there's no indication of what you really want, nor what is acceptable, nor what the constraints are.

Comment: I think you at least need some example output.

Comment: I apologize, I will try to prepare some images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it in the following way:

First, we iterate all images and gather the max dimensions for each column and row.

```
size = 3
maxWidth = {}
maxHeight = {}

for i, img in enumerate(imgs):
    col = i%size
    row = i//size

    if col not in maxWidth:
        maxWidth[col] = 0

    if row not in maxHeight:
        maxHeight[row] = 0

    if img.size[0] > maxWidth[col]:
        maxWidth[col] = img.size[0]

    if img.size[1] > maxHeight[row]:
        maxHeight[row] = img.size[1]
```

We then calculate their sums in order to determine the image size.

```
x = sum(maxWidth for maxWidth in maxWidth.values())
y = sum(maxHeight for maxHeight in maxHeight.values())

grid = Image.new('RGB', size=(x, y))
```

Then we iterate all images again and position them based on the max dimensions that we gathered. We reset and increment x1 and y1 accordingly depending on where we are.

```
for i, img in enumerate(imgs):
    col = i%size
    row = i//size

    if col == 0:
        x1 = 0
    else:
        x1 += maxWidth[col-1]

    if row == 0:
        y1 = 0
    elif col == 0:
        y1 += maxHeight[row-1]
    
    grid.paste(img, box=(x1, y1))
```

This way, there is no need to allocate more space to an image than its column/row requires.